# Can't access other public classes in the same namespace

Tags: c#

I have a few classes in a namespace called `Mafia`. Every `cs` file in the picture follows this structure:

```
    namespace Mafia {
         public class Name {

         }
    }
```

And the file name matches the class name.

[image]

I can access all classes in `EvenEmitter`, `NightAction`, `Player`, `Role`, `Roles`, `Settings`,  `Win` and `ActionManager`.

I can access `Game`, `NightAction` and `PhaseManager` from every other class as well, but I can't access any classes in `Game`, `NightAction` and `PhaseManager`.

(This is in Player.cs VVV)

[image]

You can see, I cannot access `Game`, `NightAction` and `PhaseManager` from the Mafia namespace, but I can access them like they aren't in a namespace. When I hover over them I get just `class Game / NightAction / PhaseManager`, not `class Mafia. Game` for example.

(This is in Game.cs VVV)

[image]

(Same thing happens in `NightAction` and `PhaseManager`).

So in short, I have a lot of classes in a single namespace. However, 3 of them are acting like they aren't in a namespace.

Some things I did before the problem occurred:

- I renamed the folder, then noticed the problem and renamed it back.

For those who say that I forgot to public them:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share your other classes code which you can't access also. I guess you forgot to public these classes.

Comment: @Nhan Based on "but I can access them like they aren't in a namespace" it sounds more like OP has removed the namespace declaration from around them, or they're actually in the same namespace as the code where OP is using them.

Comment: OP, please provide examples of these classes in your question, including their namespaces, etc.

Comment: Namespaces are not folders. Don't look at the folder structure; look at the namespace declarations for each class.Or use Visual Studio's Object Browser (on the View menu) and do a search for your class; it might not be where you think it is.

Comment: @John added pictures.

Comment: I can't see your images (blocked by our firewall), but just wanted to inform you that file and folder names are irrelevant. Only the namespaces and class names play a role.  (of course you want to keep your file and folder names consistent to easily locate them ;-)

Comment: @johey Yeah I know, I said that so it's easier to understand I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Weird. I deleted the project from the solution then added it back and everything was fixed. Welp, thanks for the help anyways!

Comment: You maybe just lost Visual studio by renaming folders.

Sometime restarting VS is enough.

Answer (score 0):

In a multi-project solution, it's easy to put new classes you mean for one project into another; especially when they form a closed, integrated construct.  It can be baffling to see that they have the "same" namespace, but can't see each other.  Ensure that the files are in the same project AND have the same namespace.